# How can I play youtube videos with vlc dotnet library in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, youtube, vlc

I want to develop an player app. I can play from file or rtp-udp stream with vlc dotnet library. But I can't play youtube link. can anyone help me? Thanks in advance

Comment: There's no way to know why your code doesn't work if you don't show it to us.

Comment: I am using this code to play udp stream myControl.MediaPlayer.Play(new Uri("udp://@192.168.1.44:1100")); it works fine. But when I changes the url to youtube link it doesn't play anything. myControl.MediaPlayer.Play(new Uri("http://youtu.be/-PpwtfO-P94"));

Comment: entire codes are available [link](https://vlcdotnet.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to do it following the next steps:

1) Get the download URL of the youtube Video. There is a lot of information how to do that. But to make an example I provide you the following link:
http://en.savefrom.net/1-how-to-download-youtube-video/

In the method3 you have a way to do it via "sfrom.net".
So for example if you have the youtube video: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k1K_4UkVSAE", you can use the following download url: "http://sfrom.net/https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k1K_4UkVSAE".

2) Use the previous URL with the VLCDotNet library. I load that with the LocationMedia.

Example:

```
vlcControl.Media = new LocationMedia("http://sfrom.net/https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k1K_4UkVSAE");
```

I tried that, and works.

Edit: You can use this website to obtain the direct URL of a youtubeVideo. Easier than the way I explained in the paragraph 1.
http://en.savefrom.net/#url=https:/www.youtube.com/watch?v=k1K_4UkVSAE&utm_source=sfrom.net&utm_medium=short_domains&utm_campaign=sfrom.net

Comment: Is it me or did they removed the `LocationMedia` class from the newer version of the VLCDotNet library?

Comment: Vlc.DotNet changed radically since that post. See https://github.com/ZeBobo5/Vlc.DotNet/wiki/Getting-started for the new syntax.